# Html download a file that will be generated when the button is clicked

Tags: html, download

It seems that in html5, you can do download like this:

```
<a href="path_to_file" download="proposed_file_name">Download</a>
```

The `path_to_file` will be the file you want to download. However, I need to call a back end service(like a `HTTP post`) first, so that the file will be generated in the first place, then I could download it.

What's the best solution to accomplish this? Adding a listener to the `<a` tag which triggers a call to back end?

Comment: This question is a little vague/unclear. Do you have a method or two in mind and you're just looking for validation, or are you unsure of how to do this at all?

Answer (score 1):

that link should point to a endpoint that generates the file and returns it with a response header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=your-file.whatever`